# Gnucash: How retained earnings in the balance sheet report are calculated?

Tags: finance, report, gnucash

I'm trying to figure out how `Balance sheet` report is calculated in Gnucash. I'm using `Trading accounts` and latest currency prices in the report. I understood all the figures in it except `Retained earnings`. It must be equal to `Income-Expenses`, right? In my case it is greater by 5%. Why is it so?

Comment: You are correct.  If they are not equal then what you have isn't technically a balance sheet.  My guess the final data has not been published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I first created a `Balance Sheet`, saved the report configuration, then added/edited some accounts, and then ran the report again on the previous set of accounts. So I edited the report configuration and clicked `select initial accounts` and ran the report again, then the problem was gone.